# More compact notation for $H \subseteq \Bbb R^n, f: H \to \Bbb R^m$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

In vector calculus textbooks, one encounters the definition $$H \subseteq \Bbb R^n, f: H \to \Bbb R^m$$ or something similar quite often. I am looking for a more compact notation to encapsulate the idea of $f$ being a funcion that takes some points from $\Bbb R^n$ and maps them to $\Bbb R^m$. Only later would I want to refer to $H$ as $Dom(f)$ when necessary (in order to make statements of theorems  easier to read and recall). Have you ever encountered such notation? I hope maybe there is an arrow to express this.

Comment: I use that notation, possibly in the more verbose version "$f:H\to\Bbb R^m$, where $H\subseteq \Bbb R^n$": this is because I write what I wish to read.

Comment: Some people write $f : H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. But using lot of "compact" notation might get confusing for the reader.

Comment: Fair point. I've encountered both notations from above, they are more compact indeed. However, now I am primarily looking for something like $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ such that the arrow encodes that actually $Dom(f) \subseteq \Bbb R^n$. As if $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ was the "type" of the function.